# Open dbf file from oracle database

Tags: oracle, dbf

My instructor gave me a username and password and .dbf file and tell me to open it and try to retrieve with sqlplus and oracle database

I tried to open the dbf file from excel mysql and ms server but it i gave me an error

Comment: In Oracle, look for documentation on `ALTER TABLESPACE ... ADD DATAFILE`.

Comment: That command can only be used to create new, empty data files. You can't use it to attach or import a file from another database.

Comment: Do you know what type of .dbf files it is? Usually, that's an xBase file that can be opened with dBase, (Visual) Foxpro, Clipper, etc, and what the dbf tag is for.

Answer (score 2):

Speaking as a DBA: As Littlefoot stated, you can't just read a data file from an Oracle DB. At best they are proprietary binary file formats, assuming it isn't encrypted on top of that. Nor can you take a data file from one database instance and just plug it in to another database instance. You also can't import it to mySQL or any other database engine: as a stand-alone data file it can only be properly read by its original database installation (i.e. the specific database instance that created it).

Oracle has specific tools available to copy data and/or files from one database to another, but those would generally use the RMAN backup manager (used to make physical backups) or (more likely in your case) the Datapump "Transportable Tablespace" feature.

- To restore it from an RMAN backup you would need a complete full backup of the entire source database instance: RMAN backup sets including all data files, redo logs (and perhaps archived logs), control files, parameter files, encryption keys,, and possibly more.
- To restore a transportable tablespace dump you would need your own running Oracle database instance, the correct parameters to run the impdp import utility, and the assistance/cooperation of the DBA.

You need to confirm if the file you were given is such an export dump (though the .dbf file extension would suggest not), and how you are expected to access the data. You won't be able to just "open the file".

Comment: The task is to to retrieve data from the file and then do jar file to open it

Comment: You can't open an Oracle database file without an Oracle database. Note we're all talking about Oracle RDBMS here (per your tag) and *not* mySQL. The Oracle file format is proprietary, and files are often encrypted at rest on top of that. A username and password will be meaningless without a full database to use it on. Individual files have no authentication mechanism and were never meant to be accessed in the way you're describing.

Comment: I hoped you'll see this question :)

Answer (score 0):

.DBF extension probably represents datafile; I don't think you can read it with any tool (at least, I don't know of any).

You should find an Oracle DBA who might try to help; in order to restore a database (which is contained in that file), they might need control file(s), redo log files and ... can't name what other files (I'm not a DBA).

Then, if everything goes OK, database might be started up so that you'd be able to connect to it using credentials you were given.